# Virtualbox - Turn off one interface using nat network. .

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, nat, virtual-desktop, virtual-network

I've a problem. . . I need to connect several VM to the network, the problem is I have less free IP adresses than VM.

So the solution I figured out was to create a NAT network, but also in this computer we have 2 networks interfaces . . . 1 for internet and other for the intranet.

When I create the NAT network, virtualbox don't let me pick what interface and automatically chose the internet one . . . so my VM can't access to the intranet.

**Does anyone knows how to shutdown internet interface for NAT network?**

P.S. I can't turn off the internet interface or unplugg the wire because we need the remote access in anytime.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could still use the bridge network, and just assign static ip's to your VM's. By setting the subnet mask correctly, you can make sure that your own pc can access the vm's in the network and each vm can see eachother without interfering with the existing network. If the VM's need to be in the network for all to see, make sure the DHCP server is adjusted to create a bigger IP Pool.

Comment: For example, your network has 192.168.10.x, you set your subnetmask to 255.255.254.0, now you can also use 192.168.11.x range and both ranges will see eachother if that pc has the same subnetmask set.